# NSubstitute crashes when I try to stub an overloaded constructor

Tags: c#, nsubstitute

I have the following class and constructors declared :

```
 public class StoryProvider : ReportProviderBase<StoryProvider>, IStoryProvider
{
    public StoryProvider(ICommonComponents<StoryProvider> common)
        : base(common)
    {
        Common.Logger.LogTrace("Instantiating StoryProvider");
    }

    public StoryProvider(ICommonComponents<StoryProvider> common, IEvalReports reports)
        : base(common)
    {
        Reports = reports;
        Common.Logger.LogTrace("Instantiating StoryProvider");
    }……
```

The base class has the following Declaration:

```
 public abstract class ReportProviderBase<T> : IDisposable
    where T : class
{
    public IEvalReports Reports { get; set; }

    protected ICommonComponents<T> Common { get; }

    protected ReportProviderBase(ICommonComponents<T> common)
    {
        Common = common;
        CreateProfileServerComInstance();
    }…..
```

Using Nsubstitute I declare:

```
 ICommonComponents<StoryProvider> common = GetCommonComponents<StoryProvider>();
 var reports = Substitute.For<IEvalReports>();
```

and now if I call my method under test with:

```
var provider = await Substitute.For<StoryProvider>(common).HeadlineNewsContentAsync(request);
```

it fails in `HeadlineNewsContentAsync` because Reports hasn't been instantiated.

I really want to call it using my overloaded constructor:

```
var provider = await Substitute.For<StoryProvider>(common, reports).HeadlineNewsContentAsync(request);
```

At this point it just crashes with TestInvoker.cs not found. Clearly I'm attaching `reports` in the wrong way, how should I change my invocation of this method so that it will use my overloaded constructor

Here is the function under test:

```
public HeadlineStoriesResponse HeadlineNewsContent(FrontPageContentRequest request)
    {
        EnsureConnectedToProfileServer(request.SessionId);

        var requestXml = request.XSerialise();
        var success = Reports.FrontPageOperation(requestXml, out var responseXml);
        if (!success || string.IsNullOrEmpty(responseXml) || responseXml.Contains("<FRONTPAGE_CONTENT/>"))
            return new HeadlineStoriesResponse { IsSuccess = false };

        var xml = responseXml.GetNodeFromXmlString("FRONTPAGE_CONTENT//HEADLINE_STORIES");
        var stories = xml.XDeserialise<HeadlineStoriesResponse>();
        stories.IsSuccess = true;

        return stories;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you mocking the subject under test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the subject under test is not mocked when testing.

Create an instance of the subject under test and inject the mocked dependencies.

```
//Arrange

//...

ICommonComponents<StoryProvider> common = GetCommonComponents<StoryProvider>();
var reports = Substitute.For<IEvalReports>();

var provider = new StoryProvider(common, reports);

//Act 
var actual = await provider.HeadlineNewsContentAsync(request);

//Assert
//...
```

Comment: I tried this originally, and I get the same issue when trying to set provider

Comment: Then you are excluding information in the question about the actual cause of the problem. Provide a [mcve] that can be used to give a better understanding of the error.

Comment: I haven't got anymore info to add to the question. as mentioned. If I use the first constructor where I just pass `common` it goes through the constructor as expected. This is also true if I use your code removing reports, and then I hit the same issue. As you can see from my code. The declaration of the property is on the base class and get's set in the concrete class.

Comment: It doesn't get used in that function, but it does get used in `HeadlineNewsContentAsync`. If I Use the first constructor just passing in `common` it still goes through `CreateProfileServerComInstance()` without issue.

Comment: I've added the function to the bottom of the question. If I use the first constructor, then it errors when setting `success` because `Reports` hasn't been created. Hence the need to use my overloaded constructor,

Comment: it comes up in VS2017's IDE ` TestInvoker.cs not found`

Comment: Try doing a clean and rebuild.